# jQuery, wont change value but will change other attributes

Tags: jquery

```
function send_mail( token, loader ) {
 $(".send_mail").bind( "click", function() {
  try{
   var to = $(this).attr('ref');
   var mail_form = $("#mail_form");
   mail_form.find("li:eq(0) input").val("sdsds");
   //mail_form.find("li:eq(0) input").attr("ref", "sdsds");
   //mail_form.find("li:eq(0) input").attr("value", "sdsds");
   $.fancybox(mail_form.html(), { 'autoDimensions' : false, 'width' : 360, 'height' : 200, 'transitionIn' : 'none', 'transitionOut' : 'none', 'scrolling' : 'no', 'showCloseButton' : false });
   return false;
  }catch(err){alert(err);}
 });
}
```

My problem being that the above will not work yet if I use

```
//mail_form.find("li:eq(0) input").attr("ref", "sdsds");
```

it will change the ref and even

```
//mail_form.find("li:eq(0) input").attr("value", "sdsds");
```

will not work...

Any ideas whats happening here?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery uses `elem.value = ...` and `elem['value'] = ...` when setting the `value` attribute using `val()` and `attr`, respectively. These methods don't change the actual HTML when it comes to the `value` attribute. Therefore, when you create the fancybox out of `mail_form.html()`, you're getting the original `value` attribute values, as they are still present in the HTML.

However, `setAttribute()` does change the underlying HTML `value` attribute. Try adding this after changing the values to sdsds and before calling `$.fancybox(...)`:

```
mail_form.find("li:eq(0) input").each( function() {
    this.setAttribute("value",$(this).val());
});
```